# Proper syntax for bash exec

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do the following:

```
if ps aux | grep "[t]ransporter_pulldown.py" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Script is already running. Skipping"
else
    exec "sudo STAGE=production $DIR/transporter_pulldown.py" # this line errors
fi
```

`$ sudo STAGE=production $DIR/transporter_pulldown.py` works on the command line, but in a bash script it gives me:

```
./transporter_pulldown.sh: line 9: 
exec: /Users/david/Desktop/Avails/scripts/STAGE=production 
/Users/david/Desktop/Avails/scripts/transporter_pulldown.py: 
cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

What would be the correct syntax here?

Comment: Are you sure you know what `exec` does? You probably don't need it at all here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sudo isn't a command interpreter thus its trying to execute the first argument as a command.

Instead try this:

```
exec sudo bash -c "STAGE=production $DIR/transporter_pulldown.py"
```

This creates uses a new `bash` processes to interpret the variables and execute your `python` script. Also note that `$DIR` will be interpreted by the shell you're typing in rather than the shell that is being executed. To force it to be interpreted in the new `bash` process use single quotes.